# C# SQLite and WebApi Identity not work together

Tags: c#, sqlite

I use Microsoft Identity for my Application's user manager:

```
public class UserContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public UserContext() : base("UserContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<UserContext>());
    }
}
```

it works fine for me.
After few days, my Application need to read some data from Sqlite database. so I use EF6 db-first read this database. But when I run my application, exception raised:

[image]

I don't know why Identity UserContext tell me he try to load Sqlite provider failed, connection string of UserContext's providerName is System.Data.SqlClient:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UserContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My config file settings:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="SQL Client EF6" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

I try to add System.Data.SqlClient into entityFramework section, also same error.

```
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
```

So, anyone know why this happened and how to solve it?